# Speeding up Coveo reindex

Tags: coveo

I've got a CM server with `Coveo` for Sitecore installed (free edition) and Coveo Enterprise Search on a separate server. I set up Sitecore with Coveo on CM and reindexed relatively quickly. When I set up CD, I have it point to the CM server's implementation and call the search `API/admin service/etc` on the CM. I'm running a reindex on CD now to do the initial population, but it's running incredibly slow. Like, I started it two hours ago and it's through 450ish documents of the over 42000 it has to index. And that's just `Coveo_master_index`, then I have to do `Coveo_web_index`. Is there any way to speed this up, because this is crazy. Thanks.

**UPDATE 10/24:**  I marked an answer on this one because it answered the specific question, but I've got more coming out of the scaling guide, now posted here: [Getting Coveo configured properly in a CD/CM server setup](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1766/getting-coveo-configured-properly). Thanks.

Comment: As a follow-up, it's now been almost 4-5 hours, and it's just over 900 documents. There's no way this can be normal.

Comment: You usually never index from CD servers with Coveo as it is a centralized index. You should follow the scaling guide to set your source names the same as on your CM.

Comment: Is there a use case to running the index from the CD?

Comment: @ASURA Not really. This is more of Lucene behavior. The only time I saw CD indexing was in a setup where the CD was fully isolated (database replication and all).

Comment: Any errors in your Sitecore or Crawling logs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As JF said in the comments, indexing CD should be avoided at all cost. Also, if you are using several CM, you need to configure them to avoid competition between instances. See: [developers.coveo.com/display/SitecoreV4/Coveo+for+Sitecore+Scaling+Guide](https://developers.coveo.com/x/3oAkAg)

Now indexing slowness can be caused by several factors. First of all, on the Sitecore side:

- Heavy processing done by computed fields (avoid web request or queries against the index. Use database calls instead)
- Heavy processing done by processors on the indexing pipelines.
- Way too many fields. Coveo will index all the fields on your templates by default. This is fine in a standard environment, but for a large setup, you might want to start including/excluding fields and templates. See: [developers.coveo.com/display/SitecoreV4/Understanding+the+coveoIndexingGetFields+and+coveoIndexingGetTemplates+Pipelines](https://developers.coveo.com/x/xYEUAg)

On the Coveo side, ensure that you have the proper hardware : https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/ces/7.0/administrator/coveo_platform_hardware_and_software_requirements.htm

Now if you cleared all the points above and you still have slowness, you might want to look at the Sitecore logs or the Coveo Index Logs (CES7/Logs)