# Getting Coveo configured properly in a CD/CM server setup

Tags: coveo

My environment scenario is the following:

- Database server
- CM server with CES 7 (free) installed
- CD server

I was advised to follow the Coveo scaling guide ([developers.coveo.com/display/public/SitecoreV4/Installing+Coveo+for+Sitecore+in+a+CM+or+CD+Configuration](https://developers.coveo.com/x/3oAkAg)) for hooking up the CD server such that it doesn't need to be reindexed.

However, that appears to assume:

a) I have a database named "pub" from a Sitecore scaling (which I don't - I use default core, master, web)

and

b) that I have Coveo CES installed on a separate server (I don't but our database server was our QA server and has Sitecore and CES7 on it, but the end goal is to only run the databases there, not Sitecore or Coveo).

So after following the guide as best I can, I have the following issues:

1. On CM, if I navigate to [URL]/coveo/rest, I get a 404 error. I looked this issue up and checked what was suggested, but don't see any issues that should be keeping this from working.
2. On CD, after I set up the "switch master to web" stuff, I now get a "Precondition failed: The parameter 'p_SearchIndex' must not be null" error when I hit a page with a Sitecore component.

I'm using Sitecore 8.1 Update 1, with the 222 version of Coveo for Sitecore 4. Any advice on getting my setup tuned properly would be helpful. Thanks!

Update: my CM configs from the Coveo folder are zipped up here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1654372/Coveo.zip - and my ShowConfig from my CM is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1654372/ShowConfig.txt

Comment: #1: For your /coveo/rest error, anything in the Coveo Diagnostic Page? Usually, when this endpoint fails, you see it in the diagnostic page.


#2: A precondition failed could be many things, but it is usually Coveo items that are not published in the pub database.

Comment: If you can share your configs, it might help a bit.

Comment: Or the showconfig

Comment: I linked both the config files in a zip and the showconfig output in the question.

Comment: Config for the CM seems fine, you see the virtual folder in IIS?

Comment: I see a Coveo folder in my web root with a rest folder under it, but they're just folders, not virtual it seems. The rest folder just has a web.config in it. IIS site wise, I have my server, a Coveo Diagnostic Tool, and a CES 7 Admin server.

Comment: Try a right-click + browse on the REST folder under the Coveo folder.
Also, try localhost:8080 to resolve the Search API REST response.

Let me know the output of the two tests.

Comment: If I do http://localhost:8080/coveo/rest I get "method not allowed" which is a good response I'd guess. When I do the browse on the REST folder I get a "not found" message because it doesn't have the 8080 port in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL of the Coveo/Rest extension is set in the Coveo.SearchProvider.Rest.config. Start by validating it.

The the site itself is in the Coveo.SearchProvider.config and should look like this:

```xml
<site patch:before="*[1]" name="coveorest" virtualFolder="/coveo/rest" physicalFolder="/coveo/rest" enableAnalytics="false" database="web" domain="extranet" />
```

Make sure the virtualfolder and the database are fine. Look at IIS to see if the site was added properly.

Then for your CD error, the switch master to web deletes the Coveo Master Index, if you still have a shell or a master index on your CD, make sure to disable all of this, since you should only be hitting web on the CD.

Comment: Okay, so the URL is actually with port 8080 involved to the search API. Hitting that straight (http://site:8080) gave me a "need to set up a search page" note, and hitting http://site:8080/coveo/rest gave me a "method not allowed" page, maybe because it can't do GET requests? The diagnostic page launched on my CM shows a 404 error for the Coveo Search REST endpoint though, but it's trying to use port 80 it seems to make that call.

Comment: Try localhost:8080/rest/search

Comment: Yeah, that works, I get the JSON response, or if I use the server name I get the Windows authentication box. Is the diagnostic page pointed to the wrong place somehow that it's going to /coveo/rest and giving an error?

Comment: Ok, so the issue is the local REST Endpoint coveo/rest . Can you try to browse the REST folder directly from IIS? right-click browse

Comment: If I right-click on the "rest" folder in IIS and do "manage folder > browse" I get a "requested document not found" error from Sitecore. So I know Sitecore isn't ignoring /coveo/rest which it's not supposed to.

Comment: Hum, ok, strange. I found this post: https://answers.coveo.com/questions/4837/coveo-search-rest-endpoint-not-found404

Could you validate if your issue is related or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47329/discussion-between-ken-mcandrew-and-slangevin).

Comment: This thread, through to chat, has all the correct info for my issue, so I'm marking it the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Ken,

1. You do not need a db names "Pub", in your case you can substitute "web". Also this means that you do not need to setup the index for "Pub"
2. The error on your CM indicates that there is an issue with your coveo install, since /coveo folder gets added to the web root by default.
3. The CD error could be related to the new index you are trying to add or an invalid install.

So be careful with the switch to master in your case as you do not have pub, substitute with web and do not remove indexes for web.

Thanks.